# Regex to get all JS class names in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to write a simple regex that matches all class names in a file. It should match them either with or without a space before the curly bracket.

E.g.

```
class myClass {...}
```

Returns ['myClass']

```
class myClass {....} class Foo{...}
```

Returns ['myClass', 'foo'].

And so on.

This is what I have so far but it doesnt seem to be working when there is no space befor ethe bracket:

```
([a-zA-Z_{1}][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?=\{)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [positive lookbehind and lookahead](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/the-complicated-syntax-of-lookaheads-in-javascript-regular-expressions/) :

```js
const str = 'class myClass {....} class Foo{...} class Bar   { /* this is a class comment */ }';

const result = str.match(/(?<=class\s)(\w+)(?=\s*{)/g);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I just realised that code above work but also matches things that are in a comment. E.G "class Foo{ //this is a class comment}" would return ["Foo", "comment"] how can I uniquely match if they are followed by a curly bracket (or a space before a curly bracket)

Comment: @greatTeacherOnizuka i added positive lookahead, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get not only class declarations but also class instances you might use something like (considering class names follow convention & start from a capital letter):

```
const sample = `class Foo {};
$a = new Bar;

const myConst = 42;

function thisIsAFunction(){
    console.log(123);
}

class FlowController{}

let laser = new LaserActivator()

var myVar;class NewClass{...};
`;

const classExp = /[\s;][A-Z]\w+?[({\s;]/gm;

sample.match(classExp); //[" Foo ", " Bar;", " FlowController{", " LaserActivator(", " NewClass{"]
```

Or if you don't want additional characters like spaces, semicolons, etc. to be present, you could use lookahead (something like this):

```
/[\s;][A-Z]\w+?(?=([\({\s]))/gm;
```